# SQL Injection without direct user input

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

In order to prevent SQL Injection for my site, i have used prepared statements.

Now let's say i use somewhere in my code, a simple SQL query like this :

```
    SELECT  DATA FROM DATABLE;
```

Is this code prone to injection ? Well it seems to me that's not possible to be, as there is no user input.But i just want  to be sure.

Comment: Well no, as nothing the user does can modify that literal statement.

Comment: I'd say 1) it's not prone to injection because theres no parameters to inject and 2) I don't think that query would work anyway

Comment: @AlexK. thanks for your reply!
Andrew:  of course this query would work!!If you have stored some data on your db, and want to retrieve everything from it!

Comment: Somehow related: [No user interactivity Can I still get SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22152298/53114)

Comment: @Themis, I've never seen queries in the format SELECT * DATA before.  SELECT * certainly.  Select *, DATA if you have a field called DATA but not sure about your syntax.  I am of course willing to be proven wrong, but it doesn't work in my version of SQL server.....

Comment: pretty safe, another good practice is to setup a different mysql account for the server that's using your DB with limited privileges (Like SELECT and UPDATE only, etc..)

Comment: @Andrew : You are right! I mistyped the * ! Edited my question!Thank you!

Mostafa : Great tip. Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your statement is fixed (has no outside parameters), then it is immune to injection.

So if your code looks something like this:

```
result = RunQuery("SELECT * FROM Table")
```

then you are safe, since the query will *always* be the same *everytime* and cannot be influenced by users.

Answer (score 0):

Inject is only possible if you use a variable in your query.

If you use prepaired statements with params it is not possible.

```
select * from user where id = ?
```

You cannot change this query, only the value, in that case you will just get no results

If you use

```
select * from user where id = '$id'
```

now depending on the value of $id we can have a sql inject.
If $id would be "0' or id > 0 " you will allways login ;)