# Is a server susceptible to SQLi if it does not accept user input?

Tags: php, sql, security, sqlite, sql-injection

My SQLite3 and PHP webpage does not accept user inputs, only uses PHP to build tables for connecting users to read. Is my page susceptible to SQLi from any other means as there is no user input fields or log-in?

Comment: in theory you should be fine

Comment: If users can select what they want to see, then the question is justified and details on your code would be needed, especially whether you use prepared statements or not.

Comment: There is only a single page, no selection possible at this time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152298/no-user-interactivity-can-i-still-get-sql-injection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQL injection will only exist if you have user input that manipulates SQL queries in your PHP code. If you have no forms or do not make use of any other way that alters any SQL query in your scripts, you should be fine.